# npm Can't find module even when it's imported

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, importerror

I have a express-typescript project.

when I run the project(use the  commmand `npm start`)

I get the following:

```
@ruler-mobility/ruler@1.0.0 serve /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler
> node src/app.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@ruler/configs'
Require stack:
- /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/utils/createRequestHandler.js
- /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/utils/index.js
- /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/middleware/errors/404/index.js
- /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/middleware/errors/index.js
- /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/middleware/index.js
- /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/app.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails- 
projects/ruler/src/utils/createRequestHandler.js:14:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19) {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
     requireStack: [
      '/Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/utils/createRequestHandler.js',
       '/Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/utils/index.js',
        /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/middleware/errors/404/index.js',
       '/Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/middleware/errors/index.js',
       '/Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/middleware/index.js',
       '/Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/app.js'
 ]
 }
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
```

I import the 'config' module in 1 file:

```
 /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src/utils/createRequestHandler.js'
```

by using `import { REQUEST_CONFIGS } from '../configs';`

Can someone tell me what is giving the error and if you require  more  information, pls let me know. Been at it for a day, please rescue me. Even guesses  will be appreciated  like: the  import could be circular  or anything  that you thing  could  be reason for it. Thankyou in advance

Comment: Are you sure directory `/Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler/src` contains `configs.js`? Or maybe it's a JSON file?

Comment: it' a  .ts(extension for typescript ) file.  and config is name of module.